# return std::vector<std::string> returns garbage

Tags: c++, string

I had a weird behavior of a piece code today under windows

```
std::vector<std::string> getMACs() {
  std::vector<std::string> macs;
  for(/*something*/) {
    char buffer[100];
    sprintf_s(buffer, size, "get the mac address here");
    std::string s = "";
    s.append(buffer);
    printf("mac=%s\n", s.c_str();  //print the mac address correctly
    macs.push_back(s);
  }
  return macs;
}

int main(int, char**) {
  std::vector<std::string> macs = getMACs();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < mac.size(); i++) {
    printf("mac=%s\n", macs[i]);   //prints garbage
  }
}
```

although the mac address inside the function has been printed correctly, in the main it prints garbage, the only explanation I have, that the macs vector is full of garbage strings, but how can this happen; a call to string.append(const char*), though passes by reference, the push_back() function should call the copy constructor of string, and so it should not point any more to a string reference that will turn into garbage after leaving the scope, right?

Comment: I assume you are "return"ing macs? not s?

Comment: Please post some real, compilable code.

Comment: This can't be your actual code. Please provide a compilable example.

Comment: OP, before posting your next question, please read & understand http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: well if I could post the whole compilable code,then I would. But then again I don´t prefer to post a big chunk of code and instead I posted only the relevant part. some people are kinda abusing the downvote functionality

Comment: Nobody asked for the whole compilable code. What you should post is the smallest code example that you can come up with that compiles and runs and shows the problem. That takes work on your part, but often the result of that work will be that you discover what the problem is on your own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
printf("mac=%s\n", macs[i]);   //prints garbage
```

Because `macs[i]` is of type `std::string`, and `printf` doesn't know how to handle that.  Try this:

```
printf("mac=%s\n", macs[i].c_str());
```

Or this:

```
std::cout << "mac=" << macs[i] << '\n';
```

Type safety, FTW

Answer (score 6):

You are returning a string:

```
 return s;
```

you need to return the vector:

```
return macs;
```

**Edit** after your edit, the likely cause of your problem is a mis-use of `printf`. You can iterate over the vector and print the contents like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> macs = getMACs();
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = macs.begin(); it != mac.end(); ++it) {
  std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

or, in C++11,

```
for (const auto& s : macs) {
  std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that this isn't really his (failing) code.

Comment: @moswald at this moment in time, that looks extremely likely!

Comment: its most probably because I´ve been passing to printf the parameter s instead of s.c_str, I´ll try it in the morning, thnx for the answer